# How to create Child Controller Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-controller

```
define([], function() {
    function myCtrl($scope,$http) 
    {
        $scope.test = "Course Man";

    }
    myCtrl.$inject=['$scope','$http'];
    return myCtrl;
});
```

We have separate file for each controller and lazy loaded when required.. They have corresponding entry in application.js.

Now the problem is :

I need 2-3 child controllers all linked to a parent controller.. and all are there in a single file.. so that they can be loaded..

---

Tried :

```
  define([], function() {
        function myCtrl($scope,$http) 
        {
            $scope.test = "Course Man";

        }

       function myCtrl1($scope,$http){};

        myCtrl.$inject=['$scope','$http'];
        return myCtrl;
    });
```

but, dosen't seems to be working.

**UPDATE ----**

***Parent --***

```
 define([], function() {
        function myCtrl($scope,$http) 
        {
            $scope.test = "Course Man";

        }
        myCtrl.$inject=['$scope','$http'];
        return myCtrl;
    });
```

**With another controller :**

```
define([], function() {
    function myCtrl($scope,$http) 
    {
        $scope.test = "Course Man";

    }
    return myCtrl;
});

function myCtrl1($scope,$http){

};
```

This is working .. not sure they have parent child relationship or not... confused !

Comment: what are you trying to do?? you can create separate controller for child instead!

Comment: application logic doesn't allow a separate controller.. Need to create a child controller.. in the same parent controller file.

Comment: you can nest the controller into parent, but my question. Please update with more information.. 
What is the logic u want to reuse from parent controller?

Comment: What do you mean by _"child controller inside this controller"_?

Comment: Why not just inject the "parent" as a dependency in the "child"?

Answer (score -1):

You can go the other way.

it is possible to extend a controller or make a single controller a mixin of multiple controllers.

```
module.controller('CtrlChild', ['$scope', '$controller', function ($scope, $controller) {
    // Initialize the super class and extend it.
    angular.extend(this, $controller('CtrlParent', {$scope: $scope}));
    … Additional extensions to create a mixin.
}]);
```

Comment: you can use a angular service to do repetitive logic which is recommended way